# CSS3 child combinator with *

Tags: css

I'm trying to use a CSS3 child combinator ( `>` ) to set any child of a div to `max-width: 100%;`.  In combination with `box-sizing:border-box;`, I'm trying to set it so that any content of a div is never larger than the containing div.

```
* {
    box-sizing: inherit;
}
html {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
div > * {
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

Now I have an image inside a div:

```
<div style="width: 70%;">
    <img src="foo" width="750" height="200" />
</div>
```

If 750 pixels is wider than the div's 70% width, the image breaks out of the div.  If I change the CSS to:

```
div > img {
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

...then the image shrinks to fit the div (which is what I want).  What am I missing here? Is there a known issue where the wildcard `*` just doesn't work in this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Child selector support (`>`) dates base to [IE 7](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_selectors#Browser_compatibility) and the universal selector (`*`) dates back to [IE 7](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Universal_selectors#Browser_compatibility) as well (unless you are using a namespace)

For an image you will need a `height` of `auto` to prevent it from stretching.

```css
* {
    box-sizing: inherit;
}
html {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
div > * {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div style="width: 70%;">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/750x200" width="750" height="200" />
</div>
```

Comment: OK.  In my example, is using `div > *` working like you want?  https://jsfiddle.net/mnck9qh7/

Comment: Your code works, which made me reexamine my own code more closely (the OP was a simplified version).  Some styling was creeping in from elsewhere and messing things up.